Use apoc function in a WITH statement
I would like to use an apoc function with a WITH statement but I have an error each time.
When a call the function directly in a CALL statement this is working:
CALL apoc.ml.openai.embedding(['Some Text'], ...

But when I include the function call in a WITH statement
MATCH (movie:Movie) WHERE movie.tagline IS NOT NULL
WITH movie, apoc.ml.openai.embedding(movie.tagline, 

I have a function not known error: message: Unknown function 'apoc.ml.openai.embedding' 
any idea?

apoc.ml.openai.embedding is a procedure, not a function. Only functions can be used with WITH, procedures requires CALL.
A function can only return one thing, while procedures can return more.
You can use SHOW FUNCTIONS and SHOW PROCEDURES to see what is a function and what is a procedure.
Since 5.15 there is another plugin included with the product called neo4j-genai-plugin-5.XX.0.jar. It has a version of apoc.ml.openai.embedding that works as a function, it is called genai.vector.encode and you can use with WITH as you wanted. This is also available in Aura.

great! is this genai available as standalone docker version?

It is, but only in the Enterprise edition. If you are on community edition you will have to use the APOC procedure instead. So instead of:
WITH genai.vector.encode(['Some Text'], "OpenAI", {token: $apiKey}) AS embedding
you just do like this instead:
CALL apoc.ml.openai.embedding(['Some Text'], $apiKey, {}) yield index, text, embedding

Ok, this is working with extended APOC. I don't have access to enterprise edition.
Thanks a lot, u helped a lot @Christoffer
